# Multiple inheritance makes private member accessible

Tags: c++, gcc, multiple-inheritance, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

```
class A {
    public:
            int a;
};

class B: private A {
};

class C: public A {
};

class D: public B, public C {
        D() {
                B::a = 0;
        }
};
```

This compiles even though B privately inherits A. If I remove D's inheritance of C, the compiler says a is inaccessible, like I'd expect. So is the inheritance of C confusing my compiler?

Compiler is gcc 4.4.7

Comment: Might be an interference from the diamond-inheritance rules... Which would be a bug.

Comment: @Hans: Care to be more specific? Are you suggesting an alternative?

Comment: it would be considerably more interesting without the `B::` resolution and it actually compiled. And this does *not* compile with clang 3.4 (with or without the `B::` resolution).

Comment: @WhozCraig: without the B:: is says a is ambiguous, which seems to me like another symptom of the same problem: that D can access A::a. Yeah, I'm afraid it might be my compiler.

Comment: You might want to look up the diamond problem with regards to multiple inheritance. [The diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)

Comment: I would have found it intriguing if it *would* have worked, since there is only one `a` (through `C`) that is technically accessible from `D`.

Comment: @RM: The Diamond Problem does play a part in plain a not being allowed as umbiguous, but the observed access should only be possible with `virtual` base classes A.

Comment: Although writing code like this is unnecessary, but it does bring up an interesting problem.

Comment: This is a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Of course it is unreasonable. Offhand, I don't even see where it might reasonably occur in the wild. Doesn't say there's no such unicorn.

Comment: @chuck1: Access and visibility are different, unrelated concepts. Access is checked *last*.

Comment: Have you checked that it's `B::a` that's accessed? (I'd expect so, but you never know with compilers...)

Comment: The code is also accepted by g++ 4.8.2 . `B::a` and `C::a` are accessible in `D` and are separate. `a` is ambiguous, although the error message reporting the ambiguity is also bugged (`note: candidates are: int A::a`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a genuine compiler bug, as the standard does not allow such access in

> 11.2 Accessibility of base classes and base class members

Looking for evidence outside the standard itself, WhozCraig already brought up that clang does not allow such access.

Looking for similar patterns which might be confused in gcc, there is diamon-inheritance with virtual base class A, which would have allowed such access, as the path of most access determines what protections apply.